# MYSQL Select data and Join with condition

Tags: mysql

I have three table like this, I want to select that Agus hasn't taken all subject from Table A (Reference) and show those subjects, how do I do that ??
Agus supposed to have same value on Table B like in tabel A (reference table). I want result like Table Result

```
Table A (reference)
id+-----Name+----id_sub+--Point
1-------Agus-------11-------6
2-------Agus-------22-------7
3-------Agus-------33-------8

Table B
id_Sub+---------Name+-------------Point+
11--------------Agus--------------6
22--------------Luna--------------7
11--------------Luna--------------8
33--------------Luna--------------6
22--------------Noctis------------7
11--------------Noctis------------8
33--------------Noctis------------9

Table C
id_sub+----------Subject+
11--------------Math
22--------------Biology
33--------------History
```

Table Result that I want

```
Table Result
id+------------Name+-------------Subject+
2--------------Agus--------------Biology
3--------------Agus--------------History
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @PaulSpiegel that's the problem mate, I've been working on this case for days and didn't have any solution. And I cannot fix the design because I just can't, I didn't create these table. So the point is there is no way I could fix this query problem right ??

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a solution. But your question isn't clear enough for a good answer. Please check the link posted by Strawberry.

Comment: what is the differnce between table a and b? asboth having name nd point

Answer (score 0):

You must create a select like this:

```
SELECT table_a.id, table_a.name, table_result.subject where
table_result.id = table_a.id_sub where table_a.name LIKE '%Agus% AND table_a.points >6;
```

this will give you the solution

Comment: that not the solution mate, it's not a search query. I need to show this as a result

Comment: @BillyOrigin Could you be a little bit more specific?

Comment: Queries need to conform to established syntax for the given RDBMS. Otherwise, it's just monkeys, cages, and typewriters.

Comment: I want to create a select query that show that Agus has't take Biology and History. and show it as the result ..